# How to use multi domain by one ingress on baremetal

Tags: kubernetes

I know how can i use one ingress for one domain but if i have more than one domain like below what should ido?
how should i handle DNS for ingress?**I do not want to write domain in ingress.yml**[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Ingress` element on diagram is `ingress-controller`, but nobody forbids creating individual Ingress resources for each route.

As alternative solution, you can expose service as LoadBalancer and configure external DNS service to route traffic on Kubernetes LB Service. Check [ExternalDNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) project for more information.

MetalLB and kube-router also could be useful for Bare-Metal/On-Premise K8s setup.

On my opinion, Helm/Ksonnet/Kustomize will help you with Ingress resource management too.

Comment: if i want to loadbalance between all of my node i should use BGP mode?am i right?

Comment: You need to split load balancing and DNS name resolving. They're different tasks. MetalLB is used to fill the LB Service gap in self-made Kubernetes clusters, but you also need to configure DNS service outside your Kubernetes cluster: BIND, dnsmasq, etc. Instruments such as ExternalDNS and CoreDNS help with K8s cluster configuration.

PS I don't have enough experience with MetalLB and ExternalDNS, because I usually work in cloud environment.

Comment: Yes, you can use ExternalDNS for baremetal, but the functionality in `Alpha` state. Check `Configuring RFC2136 provider` section [https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rfc2136.md](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rfc2136.md)

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rfc2136.md
it is very vauge .do you know better and simpler way?

Comment: I suppose that clean bare-metal Kubernetes cluster bootstrapping is very complex process. DNS configuration is a small part of it. You should check turn-key installers such as CoreOS Tectonic, Kubespray, Red Hat Openshift or Rancher for conformance with your tasks.

Comment: i want to use ubuntu. should i use CoreOS?

Comment: No, CoreOS is a special Linux distribution, optimized for usage as container runtime.

Nevertheless, if you want to bootstrap Kubernetes in hard way, start learning about Ansible, Packer, Vagrant and Terraform. It also a part of the complex process as networking, DNS configuration and etc.